# Mac OS X bash prompt bug?

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

I am trying to set my bash prompt to display the time and current directory in bold:

```
export PS1="\[\e[1m\][\A] \w \$ \[\e[0m\]"
```

This does apparently work, but when I use the command history (ctrl-r), after finding the command I was searching for and pressing enter, this line is not displayed correctly. Here is an example:

```
[21:58] ~/Wyona/svn-repos/zwischengas $ 
(reverse-i-search)`ta': tail -F logs/log4j-cnode1.log
```

becomes, after pressing enter:

```
[21:58] ~/Wyona/svn-repos/zwischengas $  -F logs/log4j-cnode1.log
```

Of course, this is not "really" a problem, since the command does work correctly, but it is still annoying. Does anybody know why this happens? And, more importantly, how to prevent/fix it?

Comment: The `\\[` and `\\]` are supposed to take care of what you're describing and you have a very straightforward prompt. What version of Bash (`echo $BASH_VERSION`)?

Comment: Your PS1 works fine for me without the side effects you describe. What version of OS X are you using? I'm on 10.6.3 using the bash distributed with OS X (version string: `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)`)

Comment: I have this problem also. I can reproduce the problem above on Snow Leopard. `/bin/bash` is `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release`

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this with the system bash on 10.5.0 through 10.6.4, and 
this appears to be a bug in bash 3.x.

see: http://osdir.com/ml/bug-bash-gnu/2009-07/msg00021.html

Install a new, more up to date bash (4.x) (my preferred path is Homebrew, found on github), and it should be fixed (it is for me).

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing this, too, and fixed it by jumping into Preferences > Settings > [whichever one is your default] > Advanced and setting "Declare Terminal As" to "xterm-256color", then restarting Terminal.